# Any experience of IOTA on embedded devices?

Tags: wallet, hardware-wallet

I got an issue, so I wrote a stackoverflow issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48898733/cant-resolve-library-dependencies Maybe someone is able to help me.

After writing this issue, I thought I just ask if someone is already using a IOTA light wallet on embedded devices. I speak about devices with a few KB RAM and ROM. Nothing like a Raspberry etc. with a full linux-system. If somebody is already using it, it would be nice to get some advice.

Which library are you using? 
How does your setup looks like?

/e Just to update the people coming from Google. I am working on it and already successfully created a tx bundle on a STM32F1: https://github.com/embedded-iota/micro-light-wallet

Comment: As mentioned in my answer elsewhere, we ported bits of https://github.com/IOTA-Ledger/blue-app-iota to Texas Instruments CC2650. I should probably clean up the code, stick a nice README and release it.

Comment: @kfx Yes, please. I wwould also like to ask some question. Probably it is fine to talk to your student about it.